# Sql Reader Loop contains Select that determines which data to insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, dataadapter

Hello I am new to C#/ADO  I wrote the following code.  I essentially want to open the database and create a reader using a select statement.  I then want to loop through that reader and grab a column value for use in a second sql statement.  If the ExecuteScaler is not null and I know there is only one record then I want to insert a record into a dataset with the Spindletime as the last parm.  If it is null then I want to insert the same record but with a zero for the last parm.  I want to do this check and insert for every row in the reader.  Then close up shop.  Tips on a better way to do this would be helpful.  Can I use dataadapter.fill?

here is my code

```
conn.Open

using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select Distinct PartName, OrderName, RequiredQuantity, StartDate, CompleteDate, NormalQuantity, ScrapQuantity, OrderComment from OrderResults"))
{
    using (SqlDataReader 1streader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (1streader.Read())
        {
            string strordername = reader.GetString(2);  get the ordername

            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select OrderName,
            Sum(SpindleTime) as TotalSpindle Time from MachineResults 
            Where @OrderName = strordername"))
      {
            cmd2.CommmandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValues(“@OrderName”, strordername)

                object o = cmd2.ExecuteScalar(); 
                if(o != null)  Check if record exists
                {

        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd3.Connection = conn;
  cmd3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PartResults(PartName,
      OrderName, RequiredQuantity, StartDate, CompleteDate, 
      NormalQuantity, ScrapQuantity, OrderComment,
      SpindleTime)
                         VALUES
                           (@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5, @param6, 
                            @param7, @param8, @param9)";

        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", 
        reader.GetString(1));
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", 
         reader.GetString(2));
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", 
        reader.GetString(3));
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4", 
        reader.GetString(4));
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param5", 
        reader.GetString(5));
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param6", 
        reader.GetString(6));
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param7",
        reader.GetString(7));
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param8", 
        reader.GetString(8));
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param9", TotalSpindle));

                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                   }
                    else 
                    {
          SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand();
         cmd4.Connection = conn;
   cmd4.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PartResults(PartName,
      OrderName, RequiredQuantity, StartDate, CompleteDate, 
      NormalQuantity, ScrapQuantity, OrderComment,
      SpindleTime)
                         VALUES
                           (@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5, @param6, 
                            @param7, @param8, @param9)";

        cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", 
        reader.GetString(1));
        cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", 
        reader.GetString(2));
        cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", 
        reader.GetString(3));
        cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4",
        reader.GetString(4));
        cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param5", 
        reader.GetString(5));
        cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param6", 
        reader.GetString(6));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param7",
        reader.GetString(7));
        cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param8", 
        reader.GetString(8));
        cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param9", 0));

                cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                  }
               }  

                }
        }
        1streader.Close();
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: If you don't have [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) turned on (it is not on by default if you don't specify it in the connection string) you will get a error when you try to execute `cmd2` before `reader` has been closed. Also you never set the connection for `cmd1` or `cmd2`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a reader , loop or any dataset. If i understand clear , you can achieve this with a single query like below. Try and tell me in case you need more help. I should work though.

```
INSERT INTO PartResults(PartName,
      OrderName, RequiredQuantity, StartDate, CompleteDate, 
      NormalQuantity, ScrapQuantity, OrderComment,
      SpindleTime)

  VALUES
                          Select Distinct PartName, OrderName, 
                                 RequiredQuantity, StartDate, CompleteDate, 
                                 NormalQuantity, ScrapQuantity, OrderComment,
                                 (SELECT
                                      CASE WHEN  Sum(SpindleTime) > 0 
                                     THEN            Sum(SpindleTime) 
                                      ELSE  0 END AS TotalSpindle  
                                  FROM MachineResults 
                                  WHERE OrderName =OrderResults.OrderName  ) 
                                  from OrderResults
```

Assuming OrderName  is a relation/Foreign key between OrderResults and MachineResults .IF not then replace it with the relation between the two tables.